# Joining multiple ordered arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

Lets say I have this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
c = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO']
```

And I want this:

```
d = [[1, 'a', 'ABC'], [2, 'b', 'DEF'], ...]
```

How can I accomplish this in Ruby?

I tried with `.zip`

```
r = []
r.zip(a, b, c)
puts r
```

But didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do as below :-

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
c = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO']

a.zip(b,c) 
# => [[1, "a", "ABC"], [2, "b", "DEF"], [3, "c", "GHI"], [4, "d", "JKL"], [5, "e", "MNO"]]
```

One thing to remember here - `Array#zip` returns an array of *size*, equal to the size of the *receiver array object*.

```
# returns an array of size 2, as the same as receiver array size.
[1,2].zip([1,5,7]) # => [[1, 1], [2, 5]]
# below returns empty array, as the receiver array object is also empty.
[].zip([1,2,3,4,5]) # => []
```

For the same reason as I explained above `r.zip(a, b, c)` returns `[]`.

Comment: *facepalm* - OMG, this simple... Thanks! "You can accept an answer in 10 minutes" - I'll do it later...

Comment: Worth noting: If what you actually have is an array of arrays — like `[a, b, c]` — you can use `transpose` on the outer array to get the same effect.

Comment: @Chuck Humm, if arrays are not same size.. then *error*, which `zip` silently adds `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[a,b,c].reduce(:zip).map(&:flatten)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = [a,b,c].transpose
[[1, "a", "ABC"], [2, "b", "DEF"], [3, "c", "GHI"], [4, "d", "JKL"], [5, "e", "MNO"]]
```